# Python - How to delete linked action from NLA

Tags: python

[image]

I'm trying to unlink whatever action is linked to the action editor as to make it disappear from the NLA editor. How do I do that with Python (preferably in a not-context sensitive way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object.animation_data.action = None`